# Looping in php - Creating different roll numbers

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

This is my code:

```
$roll = rand(100,1000000);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT roll FROM users") or die(mysql_error());

if($row["roll"] == $roll) {
   $roll = rand(100,1000000);
}
else
{
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (roll) VALUES('$roll') ") or die(mysql_error()); 
}

echo "Data Inserted!";
```

My question is:

If the regenerated roll number is again equal to a roll number already existing in database, how it should again generate a new roll number and keep on checking it unless it gets a unique number, which i can finally insert in the database? Please help!

Comment: You have not assigned any value of $row["roll"] in this. Also the query is not complete (are you retrieving single value using object or multiple values using array) and use mysqli or PDO instead of "mysql_*". Please provide the details.

Comment: Just a small note: Whenever you feel like using rand(), use [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) instead. For your own sanity.

Comment: I'm assuming that $roll["roll"] in the if query should be $result["roll"]?  If so, can you edit the question for clarity?

Comment: mysql functions are being deprecated, move onto PDO or use a wrapper https://github.com/tobya/pdo_mysql_functions

Comment: @TobyAllen I would seriously have to advice against the use of half-in/half-out PDO wrapper libraries like that. If you are going to use PDO, then use PDO. That *is* the new standard; no reason to get stuck somewhere in between. - If you are desperate not to move to OOP code yet, then the MySQLi extension offers a functional interface that supports all the fancy new features, like prepared statements. No need to complicate matters even further than that.

Comment: @Atli I agree for new code it is essential to use PDO properly, however there is an ENORMOUS amount of legacy PHP code out there that is going to be mysql_ forever unless there is an easier way of migrating.  These functions provide one option that moves a code base to PDO with minimal disruption.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to fetch ALL the rolls each time. It's just a waste of resources. Just check if the roll exists in the database, and if it does, check a new one.

```
function doesRollExist($roll) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE roll = " . (int)$roll;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($result) {
        return ((int)mysql_result($result, 0)) != 0;
    }
    else {
        trigger_error("Query failed: " . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

do {
    $newRoll = mt_rand(100, 1000000);
}
while (doesRollExist($newRoll));

// Now $newRoll will be a random number that doesn't exist
// in the database.
```

Comment: Hey, I manually entered a number in $roll which was already there in database, and then ran this page, but instead of generating a new roll number, it saved the same number which I entered.

Comment: When it say through the code that the roll number already exists in the database then why it didn't create a new one???

Comment: There were a couple of syntax errors in there (semi-colons), but aside from that, the code works just as expected. I even tested it, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$count = 1;
while($count > 0) {
    $roll = rand(100,1000000);
    mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `users` WHERE roll=' . mysql_real_escape($roll)) or die('Can\'t query the DB server.');
    $countRow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $count = $countRow[0];
}
```

In real-life situations you should probably add better error checking - using trigger_error, or exceptions(that of course have to be caught). I would even recommend to log all the errors.

Comment: Putting the `mysql_query` call directly into a function that expects a MySQL resource is kind of sloppy coding. You should be testing the query result for failures and handling them. (Even in example code... *Especially* in example code!)

Comment: No problem, that's much better. I would like to make one additional suggestion though. The `or die()` approach is OK for development, but it's not ideal for production code. Users should never have to see actual error messages. The `or trigger_error()` approach would be better, as that can configured to dump errors onto the page during development, and then logged to a file when code is moved to production.

Comment: You are right(again :P). I won't edit my code again, but i will edit the post and add information that error checking should be better :).

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve by this way

```
$flag=1;
while($flag==1)
{
$roll = rand(100,1000000);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT roll FROM users WHERE roll=$roll") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if($row[0] == $roll) 
{
   $roll = rand(100,1000000);
}
else
{
 $flag=0;
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO users values($roll)") or die(mysql_error()); 
  echo "Data Inserted!";
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$roll = rand(100,1000000);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT roll FROM users") or die(mysql_error());


while($row["roll"] == $roll) {
    $roll = rand(100,1000000);   
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (roll) VALUES('$roll') ") or 
die(mysql_error()); 


echo "Data Inserted!";
```